# Problem: failed to create task or type workspacePreferenceFile

Tags: eclipse, ant

I'm quite new with ANT to build an Eclipse (Oxygen) project. I'm using existing build.xml file which previously written in RAD environment.

Here is my `workspacePreferenceFile`;

```
<workspacePreferenceFile
  preferenceFileName="${rad.preferences.filename}"
  useEclipsePrefs="true"
  overwrite="true" />
```

Here is my `${rad.preferences.filename}`

```
compiler.problem.unusedImport=ignore
compiler.compliance=1.8
compiler.source=1.8
```

And here is the error

```
BUILD FAILED
Problem: failed to create task or type workspacePreferenceFile
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`workspacePreferenceFile` is only available in IBM RAD, it is not in standard Eclipse.

Eclipse preferences files use the normal Java property file format so you may be able to use the standard Ant `property` task.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.